# The output of the Wordcount is being stored in different files

Tags: apache-beam

The output of the WordCount is being stored in multiple files.
However the developer doesn't have control on where(ip,path) the files stay on cluster.
In MapReduce API, there is a provision for developers to write reduce program to address this.How to handle this in ApacheBeam with DirectRunner or any other runners?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed -- the WordCount example pipeline in Apache Beam writes its output using `TextIO.Write`, which doesn't (by default) specify the number of output shards.

By default, each runner independently decides how many shards to produce, typically based on its internal optimizations. The user can, however, control this via `.withNumShards()` API, which would force a specific number of shards. Of course, forcing a specific number may require more work from a runner, which may or may not result in a somewhat slower execution.

Regarding "where the files stay on the cluster" -- it is Apache Beam's philosophy that this complexity should be abstracted away from the user. In fact, Apache Beam raises the level of abstraction such that user don't need to worry about this. It is runner's and/or storage system's responsibility to manage this efficiently.

Perhaps to clarify -- we can make an easy parallel with low-level programming (e.g., direct assembly), vs. non-managed programming (e.g., C or C++), vs. managed (e.g., C# or Java). As you go higher in abstraction, you no longer can control data locality (e.g., processor caching), but gain power, ease of use, and portability.